# How to get the assigned port of a GrpcServer

Tags: c#, grpc

I want to create a gRPC server and bind it to a random port.

The documentation states that port 0 (`ServerPort.PickUnused = 0`) can be passed to achieve this:

```
var server = new Server
{
  Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", ServerPort.PickUnused, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
};
// ... adding some services
server.Start();
```

How can  I determine which port has been assigned to the server?
The passed `ServerPort` still mentions `0`:

```
var enumerator = server.Ports.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
var serverPort = enumerator.Current as ServerPort;
Debug.Log($"RPC Server started on port {serverPort.Port}");
// Out: RPC Server started on port 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes reading the WHOLE [documentation page](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.ServerPort.html) BEFORE googling around would save so much time.

`ServerPort` has a property named `BoundPort` (quote: "The port actually bound by the server.

This is useful if you let server pick port automatically.")

This returns the actual port:

```
Debug.Log($"RPC Server started on port {serverPort.BoundPort}");
```

Comment: How do we let the clients know about this randomly picked port number? Passing it offline through config files?

Comment: @kakyo When using a random port, the server usually expects to be contacted by processes it launches, and usually passes the port number through the command line.